# how to check the filesystem type of a logical volume

Tags: partition, hard-disk, lvm

How to check the filesystem type of a logical volume using `lvm` or any other utility?

For example, if my logical volume is `/dev/vg1/lv1` then how to check its filesystem type?

I have made a `ext4` filesystem in the logical volume using `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/vg1/lv1`. But don't know how to verify it. I could not see any option for thin is `lvm`?

Comment: Does anyone know how this is done on C/C++ level ?

Comment: Is your question where is the LVM source code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Same as you would with any other block device.  e.g.

```
file -s /dev/vg1/lv1
```

If `/dev/vg1/lv1` is a symbolic link, you'll also need `file`'s `-L` (aka `--dereference`) option to de-reference it (i.e. follow it to the real device node it's pointing to):

```
file -L -s /dev/vg1/lv1
```

BTW, it's OK to use `-L` on a regular file.

If it's ext4, it'll say something like:

```
/dev/vg1/lv1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=xxxx, volume name "yyyy" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

Alternatively, you could run `blkid /dev/vg1/lv1`.  That would report something like:

```
/dev/vg1/lv1: LABEL="yyyy" UUID="xxxx" TYPE="ext4"
```

From `man file`:

> -s, --special-files
>
> Normally, file only attempts to read and determine the type of argument files which stat(2) reports are ordinary files.  This prevents problems, because reading special files may have peculiar consequences.  Specifying the -s option causes file to also read argument files which are block or character special files.
>
> This is useful for determining the filesystem types of the data in raw disk partitions, which are block special files.  This option also causes file to disregard the file size as reported by stat(2) since on some systems it reports a zero size for raw disk partitions.

Comment: above commmands worked. Just wondering , there is no `lvm` command for this ?

Comment: Doing this on my /dev/sdb1,2,5 - which are LVM partitions outputs `/dev/sdb#: block special`

Comment: did you run just `file`, or `file -s`?   `-s` (or `--special-files`) tells `file` to identify block or character special files.  see `man file` and search for `--special-files`.

Comment: my `file` needed `--dereference` so it could see through the symbolic link of /dev/vg0/lv0

Answer (score 18):

Use `lsblk -f`.

```
$ lsblk -f
    NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL          UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
    sda                                                                                              
    ├─sda1          ext4                       d2123fec-6c94-426f-b505-8cf3441122cf    742,6M    17% /boot
    └─sda2          LVM2_member                BLt1F3-S5E3-hBRX-Eqya-AUOx-wyxc-a5Yaf4                
      ├─fedora-root xfs                        59935050-8e89-4f7f-bf0f-2f448c4c680b     12,8G    15% /
      └─fedora-swap swap                       5fbca8c7-fd22-4acf-a411-d96a100c8ab2                  [SWAP]
    sr0             iso9660     VBox_GAs_6.0.8 2019-05-13-13-58-35-65
```

Comment: it doesn't always show the logical volumes...

Answer (score 1):

If the logical volume has multiple partitions, knowing the partition offsets can be helpful.

Use `fdisk` to read the volume's partition info:

```
linux1:~ # fdisk -l /dev/vg01/lv001
Disk /dev/vg01/lv001: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000825ab

Device           Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vg01/lv0011           63   3132674   3132612  1.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/vg01/lv0012 *    3132675 167734664 164601990 78.5G 83 Linux
```

Then use `blkid` to determine the filesystem type. The `-p` option performs a deep probe bypassing the local `blkid` cache file, and capital `-O` determines the byte offset to inspect. The offset is determined by multiplying the start sector by the sector size; e.g.,

```
 `expr 3132675 \* 512`
```

where the backticks are for inlining the expression, and the backslash `\*` prevents bash from eating the asterisk.

Here's the `blkid` command used to determine the target filesystem:

```
linux1:~ # blkid -pO `expr 3132675 \* 512`   /dev/vg01/lv001
/dev/vg01/lv001: UUID="..." VERSION="1.0" TYPE="ext3" USAGE="filesystem" PTTYPE="dos"
```

which in this example is: **ext3**.

To access the filesystem, mount the offset:

```
mount -o offset=`expr 3132675 \* 512`  /dev/vg01/lv001 /mnt/lv001
```

The above operations performed on SLES 12.4:

```
linux1:~ # uname -a
Linux linux1 4.12.14-95.6-default #1 SMP Thu Jan 17 06:04:39 UTC 2019 (6af4ef8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

wipefs ( with no options ) will do it too...

```
[root@localhost backup]# wipefs /dev/mapper/d2-vmStorage
DEVICE       OFFSET TYPE UUID                                 LABEL
d2-vmStorage 0x0    xfs  141c43c0-ebdb-414a-aa8a-1a23871b9052
```

same output from file -s :

```
[root@localhost backup]# file -L -s /dev/mapper/d2-vmStorage
/dev/mapper/d2-vmStorage: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 512, v2 dirs)
```

To actually wipe the fs :

```
[root@localhost backup]# wipefs -a /dev/mapper/d2-vmStorage
/dev/mapper/d2-vmStorage: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000000 (xfs): 58 46 53 42
```